# images for carousel are not showing in firefox

Tags: html, css, carousel

The images for my carousel are not showing, only in Firefox and when you maximize the browser. I can see the controls at bottom of carousel where it says next and prev.

Everything is showing fine in chrome and IE, and when you minimize the Firefox browser.

http://www.henschen.com/siteTemplates/2014-16/

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="item"><img src="images/slider1.png" alt="test"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="images/slider2.png" alt="test"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="images/slider3.png" alt="test"></div>
</div>

#owl-demo .item img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your link for `JS` code and `CSS` they are broken

Console-

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.henschen.com/siteTemplates/2014-16/css/google-code-prettify/prettify.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.henschen.com/siteTemplates/2014-16/css/google-code-prettify/prettify.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it's because you didn't close your img tags correctly.
The Firefox Inspector gives me

```
<img alt="test" src="images/slider1.png"></img>
```

when it should be

```
<img alt="test" src="images/slider1.png" />
```

Could you try changing your code to the following:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <div class="item"><img src="images/slider1.png" alt="test" /></div>
 <div class="item"><img src="images/slider2.png" alt="test" /></div>
 <div class="item"><img src="images/slider3.png" alt="test" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried and that didn't work. The images show when I minimize the browser in firefox....just not when the browser is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure to confirm that you don't have any @media definition that takes out the carousel if that is not the case  then

look for this css definition 
"@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {"
change to
"@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d), (-moz-transform-3d) {"
some how firefox has issues with transform-3d
also
then check if you have any css definition for the carousel  that defines position . ensure to take out the position attribute and try again . Hope it works for you